# ¿Cual es la manera correcta de manejar los errores con Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Actualmente tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DatosVarios(int referencia)
        {
         try
                {
                    VariosModels varios = new VariosModels();
                    using (contexto_Entities bd = new contexto_Entities())
                    {
                        String sql = "SELECT";
                        sql += " lugar";
                        sql += ",horario";
                        sql += ",centrocosto";
                        sql += ",subcentro";
                        sql += ",cajapago";
                        sql += ",formapago";
                        sql += ",codcargo";
                        sql += " FROM fichas";
                        sql += " WHERE referencia=@referencia";

                        var parametros_sql = new object[]
                        {
                         new MySqlParameter("@referencia", MySqlDbType.Int64) { Value = referencia }
                        };

                        varios = bd.Database.SqlQuery<VariosModels>(sql, parametros_sql).FirstOrDefault();
                    }

                    return Json(new { varioJson = varios, retornoJson = 1 });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return Json(new { mensajeError = ex.Message, retornoJson = -2 });
                }
            
        }
```

Pero resulta que me salió un error: **the underlying provider failed on open**, el cual desconozco el motivo y ese error salió de repente, después no volvió a aparecer. Pero lo más me llama la atención, es que no pasó dentro del catch, sino que se detuvo en la linea donde dice varios = bd.Database.SqlQuery(sql, parametros_sql).FirstOrDefault();.

Entonces mi pregunta es,¿correcto el orden de try catch?
¿Debo declararlo dentro del using de la conexión o está bien que este afuera como ahora?
¿Cual es la forma de manejar los errores?